# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing objective-c property

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native, callback

I am bridging an objective-c library to React. In order to return the data I need, I have to use a callback. The only problem is, the native method that kicks off the process that generates the data (which is the method that I call from my React js file), is NOT the method that returns the data. In fact, there are quite a few methods between the one that I call, and the final result.

So I have a few options. Either completely rewrite the entire objective-c program (f*ck that), pass the callback function as an argument to every single method and ultimately to the final method where it will be used (this 'works' but is ugly), or a **third option which this post is about**.

I am new to objective-c (very new) so go easy on me.

Instead of passing the callback function around to every single method, I want to try and make it 'global'. My attempt at doing this looks like

```
@property(nonatomic,copy)RCTResponseSenderBlock globalCallback;
```

and the method where it is 'initialized' (which is also the method I call from js)

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startScan:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
    self.globalCallback = callback;
    ...
}
```

Now just to test that this works, I added a line of code immediately below the line where I 'initialized' my globalCallback:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(startScan:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
    self.globalCallback = callback;
    self.globalCallback(@[[NSNull null], @"Test string"]);
    ...
}
```

And it works (as far as I can tell). The callback returns "Test String" to React, and I am able to see it. So I went over to the method where I actually want to return information from and added the same line of code to it (obviously removing the one from the above example):

```
-(void)theMethodIWantToReturnFrom {
    self.globalCallback(@[[NSNull null], @"Test string"]);
    ...
}
```

However, this time it does not work. I get **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**. From what I understand, this may mean that my globalCallback has been deallocated. But whatever it means, I have not been able to figure out a solution yet. Any ideas / explainations regarding this error?

Comment: Make sure it is the same instance and that the callback isn't nil.  In fact, you should pretty much always do `if(self.globalcallback) { ... }` and possibly log if it is nil and shouldn't be.

Comment: The property is a copy.